# Is there a plugin for GEdit that allows me to add inline commments - like to-dos - to my code? Specialities described below

Tags: comments, gedit, gedit-plugin

I'd like to add comments to my code (NOT commenting out lines), specifically for the period of programming and not for later use as a documentation. I just want to chalk up some task for myself inline in the code, which should automagically disappear if I distribute only the source code file.

Aside from normal "comments" while these comment appear in the source code, I don't want them to take up any line numbers, and they should be collapsible with a single click of a button. You can think of it as a meta-document to the real document (stored in a separate text file).
The idea is from Github, where you can add comments to any line of code.